# Openssl CSR Creation with -subj is failing

Tags: bash, shell, ssl, nginx, csr

I'm having a Scirpt and I'm trying to create a self signed Cert:

```
openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp384r1 -out /etc/nginx/ssl/${MYDOMAIN}.key.pem >/dev/null 2>&1
openssl req -new -sha256 -key /etc/nginx/ssl/${MYDOMAIN}.key.pem -out /etc/nginx/ssl/csr.pem -subj "/C=/ST=/L=/O=/OU=/CN=*.${MYDOMAIN}" >/dev/null 2>&1
openssl req -x509 -days 365 -key /etc/nginx/ssl/${MYDOMAIN}.key.pem -in /etc/nginx/ssl/csr.pem -out /etc/nginx/ssl/${MYDOMAIN}.pem >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The creation of the CSR should be silent due to the -subj paramter, but it's not working at all with this line:
**openssl req -new -sha256 -key /etc/nginx/ssl/${MYDOMAIN}.key.pem -out /etc/nginx/ssl/csr.pem -subj "/C=/ST=/L=/O=/OU=/CN=*.${MYDOMAIN}" >/dev/null 2>&1**

I'm receiving an error like this:

```
[INFO] Creating self-signed SSL certificates...
No value provided for Subject Attribute C, skipped
No value provided for Subject Attribute ST, skipped
No value provided for Subject Attribute L, skipped
No value provided for Subject Attribute O, skipped
No value provided for Subject Attribute OU, skipped
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:
```

It was working in that way, before I updated Openssl to 1.1.0...

With:

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -key /etc/nginx/ssl/${MYDOMAIN}.key.pem -out /etc/nginx/ssl/csr.pem subj "/C=DE/ST=Berlin/L=Berlin/O=Privat/OU=Privat/CN=*.${MYDOMAIN}" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I'm getting this error:
[INFO] Creating self-signed SSL certificates...
unknown option subj
req [options] outfile
where options  are
[...]

Comment: Have you tried specifying a valid country code in the `subj` line? eg. `"/C=DE/ST=/L=/O=/OU=/CN=*.${MYDOMAIN}"`

Comment: See the last Code line, I added a valid country code + all other codes and I'm getting an unknown option error :/

Comment: The `-` in `-subj` is missing in your last example?

Comment: Oh my... That could be the problem... I should get some sleep :D But strange that the csr creation without a country code isn't working anymore

Comment: openssl req -new -sha256 -key /etc/nginx/ssl/${MYDOMAIN}.key.pem -out /etc/nginx/ssl/csr.pem -subj "/C=DE/ST=./L=./O=./OU=./CN=*.${MYDOMAIN}" >/dev/null 2>&1

Isnt working either... with dots and wihtout and only filled out C=DE...